# Youtube videos inside jquery tabs in Chrome

Tags: jquery, user-interface, youtube

I have a set of jquery tabs. In Chrome once you switch between tabs and start zooming in or out, the video pops out to the top left corner of the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/ncfbX/2/

Has any one managed to get rid of this bug?

====

In case someone has the same issues, I found an answer on the JQuery UI website.

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```